# Convert object to array of objects using lodash 3

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

how can i convert an object like this

```
{
  "ID_PROC_GD": "1",
  "DT_INI": "2018-06-06",
  "CD_GD": "1",
  "DT_INI_GD": "2018-05-28",
  ...
}
```

to this

```
[
  {
    "name": "DT_INI",
    "value": "2018-06-06"
  },
 ...
]
```

I am using lodash 3.10.1

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: you should search propely before posting a new question. This answer (of mine) will surely serve your purpose https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24674630/transform-object-to-array-with-lodash/45897196#45897196

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[map](https://lodash.com/docs/3.10.1#map) always returns array type, and you can use both value and key in iterator:

```
_.map(obj, (value, name) => ({name, value}))
```

```js
const obj = {
  "ID_PROC_GD": "1",
  "DT_INI": "2018-06-06",
  "CD_GD": "1",
  "DT_INI_GD": "2018-05-28",
}

const result = _.map(obj, (value, name) => ({
  name,
  value
}))

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.entries()` and `array#map`.

```js
let data = { "ID_PROC_GD": "1", "DT_INI": "2018-06-06", "CD_GD": "1", "DT_INI_GD": "2018-05-28"},
    result = Object.entries(data).map(([name, value]) => ({name, value}));
console.log(result);
```

You can use [`map`](https://lodash.com/docs/3.10.1#map)

```js
let data = { "ID_PROC_GD": "1", "DT_INI": "2018-06-06", "CD_GD": "1", "DT_INI_GD": "2018-05-28"},
    result = _.map(data, (value, name) => ({name, value}));
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 let obj = {
  "ID_PROC_GD": "1",
  "DT_INI": "2018-06-06",
  "CD_GD": "1",
  "DT_INI_GD": "2018-05-28" 
}

function getNameValObj(ele) {
  return {name: ele, value:obj[ele]};
}
 
let objList = _.flatMap(Object.keys(obj), getNameValObj);
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/21428867)

Comment: Sure your are right. The explanation to solution is, lowdash _.flatMap method flattens the array of values by running each element in collection thru iteratee and flattening the mapped results.  Method return new flattened array as per the return value of the method passed to second argument.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
let obj={
  "ID_PROC_GD": "1",
  "DT_INI": "2018-06-06",
  "CD_GD": "1",
  "DT_INI_GD": "2018-05-28",
}
_.map(obj,(item,index)=>({
    ['name']:index,
    ['value']:item
}))
```